# Using starts-with? function

Tags: clojure

I am trying out the function (starts-with?) shown here: https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.string-api.html and when I try to use it I get `Unable to resolve symbol: starts-with? in this context` error message . I modified my project dependencies too by specifying `:dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.8.0"]]` but that didn't seem to help.

Comment: You will need a reference in the source code file as well: `(:require [clojure.string :as str])`, and then `str/starts-with?` is the name of the function.

Comment: Or, if you need that function just once, type out its full name, no 'requiring' necessary: `(clojure.string/starts-with? "hello world" "hello")`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may have forgotten to require the namespace ? See the example below:

```
(ns simple.strings
  (:require [clojure.string :as str]))

(str/starts-with? "hello, world" "hello")
; true
```

Comment: I also didn't think to use .startsWith